# Regular expression that matches only the letters in a given word

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to create a regex expression which will allow the test string to match with the following conditions:

1. The test string can be any length and contain any letters.
2. ALL characters in the regex must be matched.
3. All letters in regex must be matched ONLY the number of times they are repeated in the regex expression.
4. If a letter is repeated more than once in the regex it can be consecutive in the test string or separated by other letters.
5. The letters in the test string don't have to be in the same order as the regex.

So if:

```
TEST STRING = polymmorphiiic
```

the following regex would match

```
ppy
ooyc
ciii
```

whereas the following would fail:

```
pmy
iy
yrz
```

Your help appreciated as I can get all the above satisfied.

I have tried breaking down all the requirements and creating regex string for each but I can't get over string that will cover all.

Comment: First, "*regex*" already means "*regular expression*", so "*regex expression*" is excessive. Second. your question is very unclear. It took me a while to comprehend it just to conclude that this is not a suitable task for regex.

Comment: Your conditions don't jive. Looks like a fun task though.

Comment: `ppy` is not a regexp that matches `polymmorphiiic`.

Comment: I guess what you actually mean is you want to transform `polymmorphiiic` into a regexp, and that regexp should match `ppy`, `ooyc`, and `ciii`.

Comment: Like #3 `matched ONLY the number of times they are repeated` Regex is continuous on a single match. You can match globally but that requires discontinuity (except for \G)

Comment: I agree that this is not really a good fit for regular expressions. I would use `collections.Counter()` to count the repetitions of the letters in the pattern word and the test word. Then check that every element of the test counter is in the pattern counter, and the counts are the same.

Comment: 'polymmorphiiic' is the string I won't to test (just for example) and I want to find a regex to match / test the figurines I have indicated.

Comment: @sln The regexp is just being used for testing, not returning a matching substring.

Comment: Yeah so give me a regex from the test string. The infinite number of them. Let me know if that paradigm is achievable.

Comment: You would have to [chain a lot of lookaheads (demo)](https://regex101.com/r/FmYGwa/2)

Comment: @Barmar - thats doable I think

Comment: Indeed the task is doable with regex (and such a regex can even be automatically constructed), but there are better ways. Let us point OP in the right direction after showing them (thanks @bobblebubble) how ridiculous that regex is.

Comment: True @Barmar, I could use python to take care of the 'counting' of the number of occurrences of a letter - which will take care of requirements 3 & 4 - that makes it simpler.

Comment: #3 - I got an idea. If `p` was found to have 3 letters, then regex truth is `^(?=(?:[^p]*p){3}[^p]*$)` Stack up all the other letters with counts right next to that. That solves #2 as well.

Comment: #5 - There is no constraint to this as posed. The _`out-of-order`_ is not needed at this time. A class is constructed that contains _all_ the characters, see #2.. This is done within the analysis of the target string when constructing the regex given these conditions. Indeed pre-determined _logic_, hardly generic variability.

Comment: You end up statically engineering a regex in form using variable target strings. This only allows a single _type_ of regex and that is based upon the input rules. Essentially, only a single regex can be generated per target.

Comment: What exactly are the input and output in this task?

Comment: Are you actually talking about regular expressions? They don't match like you're describing.

Comment: My previous pattern can be [a bit shortened (demo)](https://regex101.com/r/FmYGwa/5) or [without comments (single line) -> see the *unit tests*](https://regex101.com/r/FmYGwa/7) but there are much better ways as mentioned already.

Answer (score 2):

You can use re.findall() to get the matching characters out of the string.  A comparison between the sorted result and the sorted pattern will handle the differences of order and character counts.

```
import re

testString = "polymmorphiiic"

for p in ("ppy", "ooyc", "ciii", "pmy", "iy", "yrz"):
    print(p,"matches:",sorted(p) ==  sorted(re.findall(f"[{p}]",testString)))

ppy matches: True
ooyc matches: True
ciii matches: True
pmy matches: False
iy matches: False
yrz matches: False
```

Note that you don't need a regular expression to implement this process, a set is sufficient to filter on the matching characters:

```
for p in ("ppy", "ooyc", "ciii", "pmy", "iy", "yrz"):
    matches = set(p).intersection
    print(p,"matches:",sorted(p) == sorted(filter(matches,testString)))
```

Even a sequential search would work:

```
for p in ("ppy", "ooyc", "ciii", "pmy", "iy", "yrz"):
    print(p,"matches:",sorted(p) == sorted(filter(p.__contains__,testString)))
```

Comment: Thanks for these suggestions.

I had rejected a 'set' intersection way of doing things as converting the string to a set would remove letter duplicates and I needed to retain those. I would then have to 'count' each character's occurrences.

After reflection I think a straight test with the 'in' operator such as "test_string in word" would do the trick (as it appears to respect duplicates) but I was looking for a regex to test for matches in one action (see previous paragraph).